# Is there a way to batch render images from several cameras?

Tags: rendering, camera

There is one scene, but several cameras and I would like to render this over night to have one image per camera (no animation). Is this possible? I don't see a command-line switch to select which camera to render.

I'm using cycles render, if this matters.

Comment: Simplest way (even without command line): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one/3503#3503

Comment: Do you mean the method with markers?

Comment: OK I will take a look at this, I didn't use any animations and frames so far so something new to learn...

Comment: I used this method and it works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use Multi-View cameras as described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102118/29586). All that is required is to enable ‘Views’ in the Render Layer properties and configure one view per camera with a particular suffix. Set your cameras with the same name and matching suffixes - so, for example, you could have suffixes of ‘_L’, ‘_R’ and ‘_T’ for left, right and top, and name your cameras Camera_L, Camera_R and Camera_T.

When rendering you will now get an image produced for each view. Each inage file produced will bear the relevant suffix - eg, ‘0000_L.png’, ‘0000_R.png’, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I actually hacked together an addon that allows you to do this (windows compatibility only and only Blender 2.8 tested). Once installed it adds a panel to the Output Properties tab with a button for rendering all stills and a button for rendering all animations.

https://github.com/astonfuture/render-all-cameras-blender-addon