# Rendering for Adjacent Video Screens

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm new to Blender, I'm looking to create synchronised animations for adjacent video screens of the same scene.

It's sort of an 'aspect ratio' of 4 x 4K video screens x 1 video screen showing the same landscape.

Each screen is centrally controlled so they can work as a coordinated whole.

What would be the best way to render and set this up ?

For example one enormous render with a ridiculously wide aspect ratio (note they're all 4K) ? Or 4 separate renders of the scene - is there some way of splitting up portions of a camera view ?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Setup your camera view by using the extremely high coordinates. (2) Render only for a single screen (change the resolution) and use the sensor shift to grab the different portions of the viewport.

Comment: I'd potentially use multiple cameras and render each separately such as as described in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102163/29586 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102118/29586 - just position all cameras at the same point and rotate so that the edges match up.

Comment: Thanks ! Presumably breaking up the rendering would be easier on the hardware - but doing it all as one extremely wide scene might be quicker (if its possible for something that large in 4K) ?